# python re.split not working for all fields

Tags: python, regex, split

```
import re
string = "some text \n\n\nError on the field: more\n text and lines\n\n\nError on the field: some more\n lines \n\n\nError on the field: final lines"
pieces = re.split(r'(Error on the field:)', string, re.IGNORECASE)
pieces
['some text \n\n\n', 'Error on the field:', ' more\n text and lines\n\n\n', 'Error on the field:', ' some more\n lines \n\n\nError on the field: final lines']
pieces2 = re.split(r'(Error on the field:)', pieces[4], re.IGNORECASE)
pieces2
[' some more\n lines \n\n\n', 'Error on the field:', ' final lines']
```

Why is the third split of `'Error on the field:'` not being picked up in the initial split of `pieces`, but is picked up when you split `pieces[4]`?

Comment: Just use `re.split(r'(?i)(Error on the field:)', string)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

positional arguments of `re.split` are:

- regex
- string
- maxsplit (default value: unlimited)
- flags (default value: no flags)

  `split(pattern, string, maxsplit=0, flags=0)`

you're passing `re.IGNORECASE` (the value of the flag is `2`) as `maxsplit` argument (as *postional*) which explains the strange effect. It works to some point then it stops the splits as instructed after 2 splits.

Just do `flags=re.IGNORECASE` (keyword, not positional) instead and it works.

In `re.compile` you can pass that flag as positional safely: `compile(pattern, flags=0)`, and that's true for `re.match` and `re.search` as well, but not for `re.split` & `re.sub`, so it's an easy trap to fall into. When in doubt, always use pass-by-keyword for optional arguments.

Answer (score 2):

You need to state to use flags explicitly by using `flags=` when using [**re.split**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.split):

```
import re
string = "some text \n\n\nError on the field: more\n text and lines\n\n\nError on the field: some more\n lines \n\n\nError on the field: final lines"
pieces = re.split(r'(Error on the field:)', string, flags=re.I)

print(pieces)
```

**Output:**

```
['some text \n\n\n', 'Error on the field:', ' more\n text and lines\n\n\n', 'Error on the field:', ' some more\n lines \n\n\n', 'Error on the field:', ' final lines']
```

**N.B.** `re.I` is the same as `re.IGNORECASE`